# Laravel custom helper - undefined index SERVER_NAME

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1, I created a custom helper file: `custom.php` which I load in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/custom.php"
    ]
},
```

and it contains this method:

```
function website() {
    return str_replace('dashboard.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}
```

It works as expected, but every time I do `php artisan` commands, I get a call stack and this message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in /path/to/custom.php on line 4
```

Why is this so? The method returns the correct value when run from within my Laravel app.

Comment: in your composer use this code `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$_SERVER['SERVER_Name'] global variable is only accessible when running your application through a browser. It will throw an error when you run your application through php-cli/through the terminal. Change your code to

```
function website() {
    
    if(php_sapi_name() === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN')){
        // This section of the code runs when your application is being run from the terminal
        return "Some default server name, or you can use your environment to set your server name"
    }else{
        // This section of the code run when your app is being run from the browser
        return str_replace('dashboard.', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: though it did not worked for my purpose but it is a good approach and can solve many other problems.

Answer (score 4):

Artisan works on the command line, so there is no SERVER_NAME. Use something like:

```
Request::server('SERVER_NAME', 'UNKNOWN')
```

instead of $_SERVER[] to provide a default to avoid the error.

Comment: I am getting `Fatal error: Class 'Request' not found`. I'll just `isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])` for now :) Thanks

Comment: @Obay - you probably need to "use Request;" in your controller, and it would be better to use Laravel code/semantics where you can to keep consistency.

Comment: I did but it said `The use statement with non-compound name 'Request' has no effect in /path/to/custom.php on line 3`. So I added `namespace App\Helpers;` but that messed up my other helper functions, they could no longer be found by other parts of the code.

Comment: @Obay - I did assume you were using a namespace, so maybe \Request::server() is needed (guessing as I always use namespaces)

Comment: Yes I did that before adding `use Request`, this was the error: `Fatal error: Class 'Request' not found`.

Comment: You need add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because when you run this helper as usually, SERVER_NAME has something in it, because you run it from browser.

When you run Artisan command, there is not any server, that's why SERVER_NAME is empty.